# Position text over image using PHP GD Lib

Tags: php, image-processing, gd, imagettftext

I need to position some text over an image. I first create the text like so:

```
$text_box = imagecreatetruecolor($tw, $th); 
$color = imagecolorallocate($text_box, 54, 54, 54);
imagefill($text_box, 0, 0, $color );

$shadow_color = imagecolorallocate($text_box, 0, 0, 0);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($text_box, 255, 255, 255);
$blur_intensity = 1;

$text_box = $this->imagettftextblur($text_box, $size, $angle, $x+2, (($y+2)-5), $shadow_color, $fontfile, $text, $blur_intensity);
$text_box = $this->imagettftextblur($text_box, $size, $angle, $x, ($y-5), $text_color, $fontfile, $text);
```

For more info on `imagettftextblur` check it [here](https://github.com/andrewgjohnson/imagettftextblur).

This works a treat. I then want to place this text in the middle of an image:

```
imagecopymerge($img, $text_box, 0, 0, 50, 0, imagesx($text_box), imagesy($text_box), 100);
```

But this is the result I end up with:

[image]

Weirdly setting the `src_x` in `imagecopymerge` to 50 gives it a minus offset instead of being offset by 50px from the left. Plus I end up with a black section at the end of the text. Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: why shouldn't it? that `50` in your copymerge call is the `src_x` parameter. you're starting your copy at the 50,0 pixel in your original image. that means you're lopping off the leftmost 50 pixels in the source.

Comment: @MarcB: So how do I place it in the middle of the image?

Comment: @MarcB Plus the images that make up the larger image are tiled using `imagecopymerge` incrementing the x, y vals by image width / height. So if it worked there why wouldn't it work for the example I've given above?

Comment: @MarcB, so now I understand why `imagecopymerge` isn't working. How do I center the text in the middle of the image?

Answer (score 3):

The copymerge() coordinates are basically, in English, `start copying at this x,y coordinate, then copy P pixels horizontally (imagesx()) and copy Q pixels vertically (imagesy())`. That means if your textbox is 100x200, you'll be copying the pixels at `(x=50,y=0) -> (x=150,y=200)`. Note that the new termination coordinates go PAST the end of the original image.

If this is your original textbox picture, and `x` is the x=50,y=0 starting coordinate:

```
+--x-----------+
|              |
|              |
|              |
+--------------+
```

Then this is what you're actually copying:

```
+--xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
|  x            |  x
|  x            |  x
|  x            |  x
+--xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Note how the boxed `x` area has gone PAST the right-hand edge of your original image. That's why you're getting the black section. You've told GD to copy parts of your image that don't exist, so it's filling that void with black.

Comment: Great explanation, thanks. That makes perfect sense. But, I still don't know how to center the text in the middle of the image. Clearly `imagecopymerge` won't work.

Comment: you need to calculate the offsets yourself: get size of drawn text using [imageftbbox()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imageftbbox.php), then you do your copying using `(size of dest image / 2) - (size of text image / 2)` as your X offset.

Comment: I know how to work out the coordinates for positioning it. I figured it out in the end.  I just needed to change imagecopymerge to this: ($img, $text_box, 0, 0, 50, 0, imagesx($text_box), imagesy($text_box), 100);`imagecopymerge($img, $text_box, 50, 50, 0, 0, imagesx($text_box), imagesy($text_box), 100);` I had `$dst_x, $dst_y` and `$src_x, $src_y` the wrong way round. Thanks for your help.